# Using Naturalsorter gem at model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, refactoring

I'm using the "naturalsorter" gem to sort an array of Items (ActiveRecord Objects) by code

On the controller:

```
@items = Item.all
@items = Naturalsorter::Sorter.sort_version_by_method(@items, :code)
```

but i need to refactor this and put the sorting method on the model

Hi! I've tried:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base 
   def self.by_code
      Naturalsorter::Sorter.sort_version_by_method(self, 'code')
   end 
end
```

But I'm sure this is not the way... So i get

```
undefined method `sort_by_code' for #<Array:0x007ff0b4c431d0>
```

Some idea? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need this to work for any subset of `Item`s, or will the argument to `sort_version_by_method` always be `Item.all`?

Comment: Yes, i need this to work with subsets.. actually i'm working with ItemGroup.items ... that's why i need to refactor...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change this line:

```
  Naturalsorter::Sorter.sort_version_by_method(self, 'code')
```

to something like this:

```
  Naturalsorter::Sorter.sort_version_by_method(self.all, :code)
```

But I haven't tried it!

Comment: My tutor!!! Hi Blat!. I'm still getting the error.. I'm not very sure why i'm getting this undefined method `sort_by_code'. .. any idea?